# How to execute this powershell commands in a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line

I'm trying to run this powershell command:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\Mysoftware.txt
```

in a batch file. This is what i got now :

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "& {Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'; Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate; Format-Table -Autosize; > 'C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\Mysoftware.txt';}"
```

but it's telling me ">" is not a command

What i'm trying to do is get the list of all the software of a computer in the MySoftware.txt file.

Thanks for the help

Comment: backtick? Write-Output? btw, why batch but not a posh script?

Comment: You added a ; before the > that is not in the posh command that you show.

Comment: Also, this will only show you the 32 bit apps that are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ";" before redirecting to a file through ">" and use "|" to pass the output of a command to the input of the next command instead of putting ";" in the end of each command.

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "& {Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table -Autosize > 'C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\Mysoftware.txt' }"
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this line instead?

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "& {Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | export-csv 'C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\Mysoftware.csv' -nti}"
```